# Echo a href in mysql data fetch query results in PHP

Tags: php, echo, href

I have a SELECT query to fetch user id, name and email from user table.

I want to place a link to `loadwu.php` page with fetched user id argument in the fetched result table. The `echo` statement looks like this

```
echo "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['uname']}</td><td>{$row['uemail']}</td><td>{<a href="loadwu.php?id=$row['id']">Select</a>}</td></tr>";
```

The problem part in this echo statement is

```
<td>{<a href="loadwu.php?id=$row['id']">Select</a>}</td>
```

What is the correct formatting for this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes which is used with `href` attribute.

```
echo "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['uname']}</td><td>{$row['uemail']}</td><td>{<a href=\"loadwu.php?id={$row['id']}\">Select</a>}</td></tr>";
```

Comment: yours was the first ans to my post. i tried and it works perfectly. thnks @nikhil-mohan

Comment: Glad to hear, yw :) @user2649343

Comment: I don't think is a matter of faster answer but a matter of better explaination in the answer.

Comment: not faster but when i refreshed after posting my query, this was the only answer and so i tried it. and it solved my problem. that's only reason.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to escape your `"`, by not escaping them you're causing an issue to php, because the string you are echoing is ending at the first `"` of the href, then php is getting some weird words that you meant to be inside your href but they aren't because of the unescaped `"`

```
echo "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['uname']}</td><td>{$row['uemail']}</td><td>{<a href=\"loadwu.php?id=$row['id']\">Select</a>}</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just escape this part

```
  <td>{<a href=\"loadwu.php?id=$row['id']\">Select</a>}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, its simple and easy way

```
 <a href="loadwu.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
```

Comment: this will end up with having php tags opened twice, one inside the other

Answer (score 0):

try to concatenate your string correctly, if you don't want to escape your double quotes you can use single one as follow

```
echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['uname'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['uemail'].'</td>
        <td><a href="loadwu.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Select</a></td>
      </tr>';
```

Otherwise escape your double quotes

```
echo "<tr>
        <td>$row['id']</td>
        <td>$row['uname']</td>
        <td>$row['uemail']</td>
        <td><a href=\"loadwu.php?id=$row['id']\">Select</a></td>
      </tr>";
```

Comment: thnks @fabio for thorough explanation.